# AutoMapper.Mapper.Map sporadically returns object with null properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I am using Automapper in my MVC/EF application. Occasionally when I launch my application to debug (F5), AutoMapper.Mapper.Map returns a mapped object that has null property values. I need to restart for this to resolve itself. This issue also occurs when I deploy my application to a remote server. As a workaround I have to check for null properties and then manually map my object.

```
                ProductHierarchyRow mappedObj = _mapProvider.Map<VW_PROD_HIERARCHY,ProductHierarchyRow>(foundRow);
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mappedObj.DepartmentId)) //Test one of the properties
                {
                    //Manually map because Automapper has failed for some reason

                    mappedObj = new ProductHierarchyRow();
                    mappedObj.MarketChannel = foundRow.MARKETCHANNEL;
                    mappedObj.BrandId = foundRow.BRAND_ID;
                    mappedObj.BrandLabel = foundRow.BRAND_LABEL;
                    mappedObj.DivisionId = foundRow.DIVISION_ID;
                    mappedObj.DivisionLabel = foundRow.DIVISION_LABEL;
                    mappedObj.DepartmentId = foundRow.DEPARTMENT_ID;
                    mappedObj.DepartmentLabel = foundRow.DEPARTMENT_LABEL;
                    mappedObj.ClassId = foundRow.CLASS_ID;
                    mappedObj.ClassLabel = foundRow.CLASS_LABEL;
                    mappedObj.SubclassId = foundRow.SUBCLASS_ID;
                    mappedObj.SubclassLabel = foundRow.SUBCLASS_LABEL;
                }
```

Here is the mapping interface/implementation class:

```
public class MappingProvider : IMappingProvider
{
    public MappingProvider()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<VW_PROD_HIERARCHY, ProductHierarchyRow>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<VW_PROD_HIERARCHY, ProductHierarchyRow>()
                .ForMember(x => x.MarketChannel, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.MARKETCHANNEL))
                .ForMember(x => x.BrandId, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.BRAND_ID))
                .ForMember(x => x.BrandLabel, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.BRAND_LABEL))
                .ForMember(x => x.DivisionId, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.DIVISION_ID))
                .ForMember(x => x.DivisionLabel, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.DIVISION_LABEL))
                .ForMember(x => x.DepartmentId, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.DEPARTMENT_ID))
                .ForMember(x => x.DepartmentLabel, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.DEPARTMENT_LABEL))
                .ForMember(x => x.ClassId, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.CLASS_ID))
                .ForMember(x => x.ClassLabel, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.CLASS_LABEL))
                .ForMember(x => x.SubclassId, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.SUBCLASS_ID))
                .ForMember(x => x.SubclassLabel, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.SUBCLASS_LABEL));

    }

    public T1 Map<T, T1>(T entry)
    {
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<T, T1>(entry);
    }

    public T1 Map<T, T1>(T source, T1 dest)
    {
        return (T1)AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(source, dest, typeof(T), typeof(T1));
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? Tips of how to troubleshoot? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those CreateMaps should only be called once per AppDomain, at startup. Make sure those are called at App_Start. What's happening is you have competing threads calling CreateMap and Map at the same time.

Comment: My suspicion also. Seems like a race condition.